# Does synchronized(a) also protect against concurrent execution of a's synchronized methods?

Tags: java

I have a class that acts as a synchronization guard. It does this by synchronizing its methods. This class also has a periodic listener that can be invoked by other threads. I'm wondering if using this object in a synchronization block will prevent the synchronized methods from executing as well. Here is an example:

```
public class A {
    MyStatefulObject o = new MyStatefulObject();

    public synchronized void doSomething(int a) {
        o.someMethod(a); // o.someMethod cannot be executed concurrently
    }

    public Listener listener = new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void interfaceMethod() {
            synchronized(A.this) {
                A.this.o.someMethod(500); // Is this safe?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it will. Because when you use *synchronized* on *non-static* method, monitor is *current class instance*, i.e. *A.this* locks exactly same monitor object. - more info https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

Comment: Yep, basically `synchronized foo() { ... }` is a shortcut for `foo() { synchronized(this) { ... } }`.

Comment: @oleg.cherednik the documentation you provided does not state that `this` is used as the monitor object.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I believe you do. The listener is not executing a synchronized method on `A.this`. Left unsynchronized, concurrent calls to o.someMethod might be executed.

Comment: @oleg.cherednik Actually upon further reading, it does state that "The intrinsic lock of an object is used for synchronized methods. When an object is passed into a synchronized block, then the intrinsic lock of that object is used for the synchronization of the block." That does seem to imply guaranteed mutual exclusion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if 2 threads have the same instance of `A` and one thread calls `listener.interfaceMethod()`, the other thread calling `doSomething()` on the same instance will be blocked until the `synchronized` block in the `interfaceMethod()` finishes.

Comment: Do you know where this is defined? I can't find any documentation that states this.